# Set http request headers via websphere application server admin console

Tags: java, websphere

Is it possible to set http request Header (Like Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';") in websphere application server admin console?

Answer (score 1):

The websphere application server's admin console does not provide a way to set request headers (neither for it, nor applications running on the server).
I'd instead recommend setting the headers via a java servlet filter or an edge/proxy server.